# Как связать PyCharm с GitBash?

Tags: git, pycharm, git-commit, git-bash

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы во время создания коммита открывался редактор PyCharm.

Что бы я не делал, все заканчивается примерно этим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Путь к папке с PyCharm:`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains`

Название программы:`PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3`

Что делать?

Comment: ¿Что печатает команда `git config --get "core.editor"`?

Comment: 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3' --wait

Comment: Расширение файла что ли не указано.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Что бы все работало в вашем случае все работало пропишите

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains\pycharm64.exe' -m"
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).